# How to say "any" in a negative phrase

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

How would I say, for example, "I couldn't find any food"?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If I wish to say "any," do I just use "de"?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/16563/if-i-wish-to-say-any-do-i-just-use-de)

Comment: Frankly, I doubt a French person would say that like that. What do you mean by food, you mean like food in the kitchen? Do you mean: something to eat? Please provide context.

Comment: @Lambie I was referring to food in a refrigerator, for example.

Comment: @Feelew It seems to be a duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to sound formal, I'm thinking of

**Le/la moindre**

> Je n'ai pas trouvé la moindre nourriture
>
> Je n'en ai pas le moindre doute

If you want to sound casual, like anyone in France (because the above answer if very fancy), you should go for :

> Je n'ai pas trouvé de nourriture.

Just put nothing.
I don't feel like this is any different from the affirmative form.

Comment: Je n'ai trouvé aucune nourriture dans le frigo. C'était vide.

Comment: @Lambie C'est très bien aussi ! Et c'est entre mes deux solutions, point de vue formel/informel :) !

Comment: Thank you. If I were to translate the first sentence of the formal form, it would be, "I did not find the least (or lowest) food", right? If that is the case, then it sounds more emphatic than the informal form, which just uses the partitive article. Thank you again.

Comment: That's correct ! Glad I could help !